# How do you calculate the offset to the client area in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I want to position a modal dialog (progress window) at the top right corner of the parent window client area.

This code will put it in the corner of the non-client area, but how do I calculate the offset to the client area?

```
this.Owner=owner;
this.Left=owner.Left+owner.ActualWidth-Width;
this.Top=owner.Top;
```

Edit:

I found this 'solution' that works for normal windows:

```
this.Left=owner.Left+owner.ActualWidth-Width-SystemParameters.ResizeFrameVerticalBorderWidth;
this.Top=owner.Top+SystemParameters.ResizeFrameHorizontalBorderHeight+SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeight;
```

This would however fail for windows that have customized borders.

EDIT:

The code should work regardless of the systems DPI setting (e.g. 120 instead of 96).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your window content is a subclass of UIElement (which is normally the case), you can simply check the area covered by the Content:

```
Matrix scaling = PresentationSource.FromVisual(windowContent)
                   .CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;

UIElement windowContent = owner.Content as UIElement;

Point upperRightRelativeToContent = new Point(
  windowContent.RenderSize.Width + owner.Margin.Right,
  -owner.Margin.Top);

Point upperRightRelativeToScreen =
  windowContent.PointToScreen(upperRightRelativeToContent);

Point upperRightScaled =
  scaling.Transform(upperRightRelativeToScreen);

this.Owner = owner;
this.Left = upperRightScaled.X - this.Width;
this.Top = upperRightScaled.Y;
```

If you have a strange situation where you want this to work for arbitrary `Window.Content`, you'll have to search the window's visual tree using `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildCount()` and `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()` until you come to a `ContentPresenter` whose `Content` property matches that of the `Window`, and use its first visual child as "windowContent" in the above code.

Comment: Thanks but this code appears to only work on systems that are set to 96 DPI. Maybe this is a WPF bug but I need it to work on 120 DPI as well.

Comment: I forgot to include the scaling using TransformFromDevice.  I've added the required code to my answer, so now this will work at any DPI.

Comment: Works great, thanks. I only found an issue when the windowContent has a margin. In that case you also have to adjust upperRightRelativeToContent for ((FrameworkElement)windowContent).Margin.